How do i make a calculated column in pivot table?
I have created a pivot table from this original dataset.
Original Dataset
the pivot table:
Pivot Table
how do i add a calculated column of "Crime not Cleared" which is Actual Incidents-(Cleared by Charge+ Cleared Otherwise) .
Any help will be greatly appreciated. I don't have much experience with nested columns in pivot table
Tried to watch YouTube and ChatGPT couldn't find a suitable result

Yes, you can!
In Google Sheets
When editing the Pivot-table, click the "Add value". (Where you currently have 'Actual Incidents', 'Cleared by Charge' and 'Cleared Otherwise'.
Pick the option at the top named 'Calculate field'.
There, enter the following formula:
='Actual Incidents' - ('Cleared by Charge'-'Cleared Otherwise')
This should create a new column with values based on the aforementioned formula.
Official Google Sheets documentation for 'Create & use pivot tables'
In Excel
Select the Pivot-table. In the top ribbon, go to 'PivotTable Analyze', then to the item 'Fields, Items & Sets'. When clicking this, select 'Calculated Field...'.
There, you will have a list of all available fields that you can pick from. You can also type the formula directly. Remember to surround columns containing spaces with single-quotes ('). Like so:
='Actual Incidents' - ('Cleared by Charge'-'Cleared Otherwise')
This should create a new column with values based on the aforementioned formula.
Official Excel documentation for 'Calculate fields in a PivotTable'
